# php Jquery - Server side - Add an edit button

Tags: php, jquery

I have a datatable that loads about 20,000 (minimum) numbers (rows of data) . With that said , i use the pipeline feature of jquery datatables since it easily handles a large chunk of data .

The issue is that i want to know how to add a new row dynamically by passing the id to it .

Below is my jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    available_numbers();    
    function available_numbers(){
        $('#available_numbers').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
            url: 'fetch_available_numbers.php',
            pages: 5 
        })
    } );
    }
} );
```

And below is the table :

```
<table id="available_numbers" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Assigned To (User Group)</th>
        </tr>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Assigned To (User Group)</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

The values are fetched in json format , just like the server side script in datatables .

Thanks.

Comment: You should start with a properly defined table with all the tags properly started and terminated. However what have you tried for yourself?

Comment: I have not tried anything as there is absolutely no guidance on how to use server side pipeline feature with dynamic adding of rows .

Comment: Properly defined table with tags ?? ...i am not sure how that even has anything to do with my actual query .Thanks for the response though.

Comment: `<thead>` has a closing tag `</thead>` you will also require a `<tbody>...</tbody>` javascript works more reliably when the table is propery defined in the first place. [See manual](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html)

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Sorry to say this but i guess you should look into how server side pipeline feature works in the manual . You don't need to define the table body since it is populated from the jquery dynamically via the json response .